# Queue of requests with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I need to implement synchronous calls with `RxJava` and `Retrofit`.I have an `ArrayList` of ids. I need to iterate this array and make the call to the web server for each id using `Retrofit` but I know how to do this only async, could U tell me how to do this like in queue when after one call finished the next one starts.

Comment: If you have the `onSuccess` callback then you can create a method and pass array object iterated by index incremented every time your `onSuccess` is called until your index is same as the size of your array.

Comment: I thought about that, but maybe the RxJava has a more clearly implementation for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is worded quite ambiguous, but I think I might have understood it. Starting from a list of items you can create an observable of these with `from()`. This values can be mapped afterwards your API calls. Using `concatMap()` guarantees the order of your results, so you effectively get an observable over your results. Which these you can do whatever you want, even call `toBlocking()` on it and make the observable synchronous. But there should not be any need for this.

```
List<Result> results =
        Observable.from(ids)
                  .concatMap(id -> callToWebServer(id))
                  .toList()
                  .toBlocking()
                  .single();
```

Comment: what does .single() method do?

Comment: Gives you the first item and throws if there's more or less.

Comment: Consider adding more information to your question. Usually there's a reason for something to be not working. Errors, missing behavior, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This code will execute them synchronious

```
Observable.from(ids)
          .map(id -> callToWebServer(id).toBlocking().first())
```

But you need to handle all network errors from **callToWebServer()** carefully in **map()**.